# Restangular ignores setBaseUrl

Tags: angularjs, restangular

The app runs on http://domain1 an must request data from http://domain2 with the following code:

```
'use strict';

// Declare app level module which depends on views, and components
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', [
  'ngRoute',
  'restangular'
]);

myApp.config(['$routeProvider', 'RestangularProvider', function($routeProvider, RestangularProvider) {
  $routeProvider.when('/view1', {
      templateUrl: '/view1.html',
      controller: 'View1Ctrl'
    });

  $routeProvider.otherwise({redirectTo: '/view1'});
  RestangularProvider.setBaseUrl("http://domain2/");
}]); 

var rest = null;
myApp.controller('View1Ctrl', ['$scope', 'Restangular', function($scope, Restangular) {
  rest = Restangular;
  var cursos = Restangular.one("resource",100).get()
}]);
```

Nonetheless, the request goes to http://domain1. What is going on? I also inspected the Restangular configuration, by putting Restangular in the global scope, as the rest variable, and the base url seems is property set.

Answer (score 0):

Hey you can create a `factory` and use different domain to get data something like below

```
(function () {
   'use strict';
angular.module('app')
    .factory('Domain2Restangular', ['Restangular',   Domain2RestangularFunction]);

function Domain2RestangularFunction(  Restangular) {
    return Restangular.withConfig(function(RestangularConfigurer) {
        var baseURL = 'http://domain2';
        RestangularConfigurer.setBaseUrl(baseURL);
        RestangularConfigurer.setDefaultHeaders({'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=utf-8' });
    });
}

}());
```

You can invoke

```
 return Domain2Restangular.all('')
            .post(data)
            .then(function(response) {
                return response;
            }, function(error) {
                return error
     });
```